# Seeing how Independent Random Variables are Uncorrelated

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, random-variables

In my textbook for my measure theory class (*Marek Capinski and Ekkehard Kopp:
Measure, Integral and Probability*), in the chapter on *the independence of two random variables*, the author(s) make the following claim after defining the covariance of two random variables and correlation:

> As we can see $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)= \mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$, so clearly independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated; it is sufficient to take $f(x)=x-\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $g(x)=x-\mathbb{E}(Y)$ in theorem $5.18$.

Where theorem $5.18$ states:

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $\mathbb{E}(f(X)g(Y))=\mathbb{E}(f(X))\mathbb{E}(g(Y))$ holds for all Borel measurable bounded functions $f,g$.

**My question:**

Since the author did not provide a proof, i'm not understanding how using $f(x)=x-\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $g(x)=x-\mathbb{E}(Y)$ in theorem $5.18$ shows that independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. If any one could explain or provide insight, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose two random variables are independent. Then (choose identity functions) $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

It remains to note that

$$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y).$$

EDIT: Using the given functions, we have

$$Cov(X,Y)=E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))=E(X-E(X))E(Y-E(Y))=0$$

Comment: I understand that if two random variables are independent then $0=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$, but my question is how do we *show* this using the information the author provided us?

Comment: Just wondering–is there any reason the author chose to define $f(x) = x - \mathbb{E}(X)$ and $g(y) = y - \mathbb{E}(Y)$ instead of simply letting $f(x) = x$ and $g(y) = y$?

Comment: @Octave Perhaps the intention was to use the classic definition of covariance.